# Views output does not match actual output

Tags: views, 8

I have a view that I finally got to work in the view preview. Then I go to the link that should give me the same result at the preview and I get the no results behaviour. I double-checked that the view is saved and I cleared the cache. [image: view edit page]

When I visit the url in the preview area, I do not get the result in the preview. Any ideas of what I did wrong?

Comment: Do you visit the URL in the same session/as the same user? What does your URL actually reads? Cheers!

Comment: What url are you visiting? 

If you visit /fivepointville/footwear then you shouldn't get the results. 
If you visit /locations/fivepointville/department/footwear then you should expect the same results.

Comment: How did you set up your contextual filters? are they getting the values from the `%` ?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I found my answer. See the solution I posted. For the sake of others who have a similar problem, I will answer your questions:
1. yes, it was the same user, same session, same browser  
2. The url was /locations/fivepointville/department/footerwear  
3. The filters get raw value from the url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Honestly, I was being a derp and a noob. Maybe I just needed time to think about it before posting a question. I will answer it here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.

**Make sure you do not have any other views using the same url pattern!**

This is a view I have been trying to make work for a while because I needed to reference two different vocabularies that were attached to the content type: location and department. It proved to be slightly more complicated than a typical view because of the two vocabularies and because of Drupal 8 which I am still getting used to. I forgot to delete or disable the previous view I was trying to figure it out in. When I deleted the old view that didn't work (but used the same url pattern), everything was fine.